# Return data based on condition in Linq C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have below query but it throws error

> An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query
> parameter expression

```
int? status = null;
BankDBContext.AccountDBs.Where(x => x.IsActive == (!status.HasValue? x.IsActive : (status.Value == 1))).ToList();
```

I want to return all records if status is null and if status has 1 return active records else in active records.

Thanks.

Comment: EF6 or EF Core? If EF Core, what version?

Comment: What is status? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Return everything if null, active items if 1, else inactive

```
BankDBContext.AccountDBs.Where(x => status == null || x.IsActive == (status == 1))
```